# How to solve iOS 9 Auto Layout issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I know this is a really easy and basic question but this is my 3rd day with this little problem. I know this is a little problem for advanced iOS programmers. I have an app which contains 1 text field, 1 button, 1 background, 1 logo, and 5 labels.

I want to see the same view when I launch at iPhone 4 or iPhone 6, etc. I know I have to use auto layout and constrains but I just started and it's really my 3rd day that I couldn't save the problem.

Can someone please help me? I'm so tired of this

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your storyboard and paste in any custom constraint code you wrote.

Comment: i didnt write any constraint code, im trying to solve problem by adding constaints on storyboard. here is my storyboard on 4.7inc     http://i63.tinypic.com/w823kj.png

Comment: What do you mean by "same view"? Should it scale or do you want to scroll?

Comment: I mean im just using portrait. So i dont need to design for rotated devices. Same view means, i have a design of my app, but when i launch on iphone4 the button is going smaller, labels are being bigger. I want to see my app's design same on all devices. For example if you run whatsapp on iphone 4-5-6 you see same views. But when i run my app, everything changes. Can you please help about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints you'll want to add. By the way, you should become comfortable making dynamic layouts and auto layout in storyboards if you want to make an app.

### Background

- Top to top of view
- Right to right of view
- Left to left of view
- Bottom to bottom of view

### Karabuk University Image

- Center Horizontally in view
- width and height in aspect ratio
- Current position from top margin of view
- Left to leading & right to trailing of Not Hesa Button (below)

### Not Hesaplama Button

- Height set
- Distance from Karabuk University Image (above) set
- Left and right 40 from left and right margins
- Center horizontally in view

### Hesapla Button

- Center Horizontally in view
- Height set
- Leading and Trailing equal to Not Hesaplama Button (above) Leading and Trailing
- Distance to Not Hesamplama Button set

### Ad At Bottom

(p.s. iAd is being shut down, look at Google AdMob or Amazon Ads)

- Bottom to bottom of view
- Left to left of view
- Right to right of view
- Height set

Don't just copy it, try to understand it and incorporate for the rest of your app. Good AutoLayout tutorials: [Ray Wenderlich AutoLayout for iOS 9](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: Thank you for your time, i will try to do it and let you know about this. Thanks again